# Why did this not save?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

```
NSString *senderName = [sender currentTitle];
NSLog(@"Text to be Saved = %@",senderName);
[name setObject:senderName forKey:@"key"];
NSString *TextActuallySaved = [name stringForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"Text actually Saved = %@", TextActuallySaved);
```

So I have this code, And when I run it I get this in the console:

```
appName[19556:f803] Text to be Saved = SCV
appName[19556:f803] Text actually Saved = (null)
```

So, what did I do wrong? I declared a NSUserDefault object in the header at the @interface like so:

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController  {
NSUserDefaults *name;
}
```

All this code is in a ViewController as it is getting pushed. So is that why? If so is there  a way to get around that?
This is seriously bugging me. Any help would be much appreciated. THANKS!

Here is my Init code

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init])
{
    name = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: To save the next question (how come it doesn't save although it does???) don't forget to call [name synchronize] at the end of your method.

Comment: Tried that also, doesn't make a difference to the output.

Comment: Put this just above your attempt to save, to verify the object. NSLog(@"MyUserDefaultsObject:%@",name);

Comment: It returns (null) as well. So the object is not being written.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually set that ivar to a defaults object?

```
name = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

You would typically do such thing in your init method.

---

Im guessing this because in ObjectiveC nil can have methods called on it, all of what return nil.  So if `name` is nil, then it will silently fail to save, then call return nil when you try read it back.

Comment: Alright so I did that in my init method, and It still didn't work

Comment: Copy his line of code into your init method or viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @theCodeMonsters - that will be autoreleased, you need to retain it as well or make name a retained property and set it via self.name =.

Comment: `self.name` should not be used within the `init` method, so the line should read `name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain];`. Later you could do `self.name = nil;` to release it. And then, when you do `[name setObject:senderName forKey:@"key"];`, don't forget to `sync` to get the value actually written.

Comment: I'm in Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) mode. All the release and retain stuff is done at the compiler level. I did try to do this with a retain property but It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most Objects the designated initializer for a `UIViewController` is not `init`. I see now that you did say that this is a ViewController, sorry I missed it before. The designated initializer for a `UIViewController` is either `initWithCoder` or `initWithFrame`, one of those to will be called for initialization. Which leads to problems, 'where do I put my setup code', this has been discussed on SO before.

In fact I'd wager that if you put `NSLog(@"Init");` in your `init` method you'd see it's never called. Therefore it can never assign your `ivar`.

For simplicity if you are subclassing `UIViewController` and want to do initialization that doesn't HAVE to be in an init method the you use `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    name = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Thats great but now I'm getting: current name: <NSUserDefaults: 0x6853b50>. I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: Take it as evidence that you now have an actual NSUserDefaults object to work with.